# How to internally add /blog/ to the url with .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Hi I have wordpress installation in subfolder /blog/, as it has to co-exist with other legacy cms, so now if i wish to access some page of wordpress i need to use links as 
www.domain.com/blog/news/ and would like to rather use www.domain.com/news/.

So basically for certain links i need to add this /blog/ somehow internally so wordpress
would handle it normally.

Please note it will be few links so rewrite rules can be literal.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting URI's for wordpress can always be kind of sketchy because wordpress has its own way to do routing and may not play nicely with other rewriting sometimes, but you can try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?news/some-page$ /blog/news/some-page [L]
```

As long as they're before any other wordpress related rules.